# Can't run mocha, opens editor to mocha.js

Tags: npm, mocha.js

I'm trying to setup mocha tests in my project using the globally installed `mocha`, which is the latest version (1.7.7 at the time of writing).

Instead of doing something, it opens my default editor and opens the file mocha.js. Running `mocha` does this; `mocha test .`, `mocha --help`, and `npm test` also gives the same result. Installing it locally produced the same effect.

Is this just some configuration error? Maybe I've missed a step during  setup? Please advise me on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I was just being dull. I had run `mocha init .`, which somehow messed it up.

Removing the generated `mocha.js` and `mocha.css` files did the trick.

If anyone could explain why this happens though, that'd be great! :)